# SKYPE4COMLib and Attach() in delphi and c#

Tags: c#, delphi

To use SkypeApi we need to Attach to skype process. I made it in C# and i have permamental access , and i all time can use it without approve from skype.
How can i make permanental access in delphi without approve from skype? 
code written on C#

```
Skype skype = new Skype();
skype.Attach(8, true);
```

and the same code on Delphi xe4

```
skype:=TSkype.Create(nil);
Skype.Attach(8,true);
```

I have a message( Take controll or Deny Acccess) ; 
[image]
How can i take off this message even i make Attach() ?

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand what you are asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: sorry , post edited...

Comment: You have to grant an executable access rights from within Skype. Tools..Options..Advanced..Manage Other Program's Access To Skype. Have you given your new Delphi executable permission to use Skype without prompting as you presumably did with your C# one?

Answer (score 0):

You just click the Button "Take controll", is the left button